# How to toggle animation in jQuery 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event to toggle animation (expand/collapse), The problem is that I'm using jQuery 2.0 where toggle is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9+.

Is there a way to use toggle for this animation?

```
$("#expand").on("click", function(){
        var el = $("#text"), curHeight = el.height(), 
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cV9a9/)</kbd>

Comment: Could always use a click event with a flag and an if statement to 100% mimic the functionality of .toggle with two events, however, there's likely a much dryer way of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use HTML5's data API to accomplish toggling with a click. This just switches the flag at the end of each click, animating to a height dependant on whether or not the div is currently open:

```
$("#expand").data("open",false).on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this), flag = $this.data("open");
    var el = $("#text"), curHeight = el.height(), 
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: flag?24:autoHeight}, 1000);
    $this.data("open",!flag);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cV9a9/5/)

Comment: Glad to have helped. May I suggest also adding a `.stop(true,false)` before that animation (:

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class eg. `opened` to rapresent the current status of the control and change the code accordingly if the element have or not that class.

Code:

```
$("#expand").on("click", function () {
    var el = $("#text"),
        curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    if (el.hasClass('opened')) autoHeight="24px"
    el.height(curHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight
    }, 1000);
    el.toggleClass('opened')
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9DBsu/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.slideToggle()` instead: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV9a9/4/).

```
$("#expand").click(function(){
    $("div#text").slideToggle("slow");                            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, just remeber a state and the initial height

```
check=false;
bla=false;
$("#expand").on("click", function(){
    if(!check){
        check=true;
        var el = $("#text"), curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        bla=curHeight;
        el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
    }else{
        var el = $("#text");
        el.animate({height: bla}, 1000);
        check=false;
    }
});
```